# SBT. Включить классы другого подпроекта при сборке

Tags: scala, sbt

Есть примерно такая структура проекта:
IdeaProjects\
 |—P3\
  |—P1\
  |—P2\
  |—build.sbt
,где `P1` и `P2` подпроекты.
Суть второго проекта сводится к тому, что он модифицирует первый проект. Его `jar` должен быть таким-же, как `jar` первого проекта, плюс свои файлы.
Для того чтоб включить классы первого проекта, общий `build.sbt` выглядит так:

```
lazy val P1 = project

lazy val P2 = project.dependsOn(P1).settings(
    mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("com.company.Main")   // Это точка входа первого проекта
)
```

Если запустить второй проект `sbt P2/run`, то, как положено, выполнится main метод первого проекта.
Но когда собираю `sbt P2/clean P2/package`, то в собранном `P2.jar` отсутствуют классы первого проекта, а в манифесте `Main-Class` указывает на main метод второго проекта, а не первого.

**UPD:**

Добавил строку:

```
mainClass in (Compile, packageBin) := Some("com.company.Main")
```

Теперь в манифесте стоит правильный main из первого проекта. Однако классов первого проекта в `P2.jar` по-прежнему нет.

**UPD2:**

Не нужна эта строка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение проблемы в использовании [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) - плагина, для создания так называемых `fat jar`, включающего все зависимости:

- Идем в папку `project` корневого проекта. Открываем файл `plugins.sbt`(если такого нет, то создаем его).
- Добавляем туда строку `addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "<Сюда пишем актуальную версию>")`
- `build.sbt` корневого проекта:

> ```
> lazy val P1 = project
>
> lazy val P2 = project.dependsOn(P1).settings(
>     mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("main.Hello")
>     ,mainClass in assembly := Some("main.Hello")
> )
> ```

- Наслаждаемся результатом, ведь теперь `P2.jar` содержит все классы первого и второго проекта, а также верный путь до main метода в манифесте